# Learning PHP which had been asked me before

Tags: php, html

I have 3 input fields and the one value(For ex:$total) , now what i am trying to achieve is if the value of the input field  changes the total value of three fields will always be equal to $total

And the code which i have written is but

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b'];
 $c = $_POST['c'];
 $tot = 6;
 if(($c + $a + $b) != $tot){
  $c = $tot - ($a + $c);
  $b = $tot - ($a + $c);
  $a = $tot - ($b +$c); 
   }}?>
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $a;?>">
<input type="text" name="b" value="<?php echo $b;?>">
<input type="text" name="c" value="<?php echo $c;?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I did some big mistake which i am not able to figure it out.I am trying for learning purpose. (It should also include -ve value in the input field) Kindly take a look.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have a fundamental logic problem here. As stated, there's no clear answer for how this should work at all. You need to clearly formulate the task on paper first with a few examples before even attempting to code this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save values w.r.t variable name correctly,

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b']; // here you were saving $_POST['c'] value
 $c = $_POST['c'];
 $tot = 6;
 if(($c + $a + $b) != $tot){
  $c = $tot - ($a + $c);
  $b = $tot - ($a + $c);
  $a = $tot - ($b +$c); 
}}?>
```